# How do I set report type for Amazon MWS report api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-mws

I have ordered this Transaction report from Amazon seller central because one can't request from Report's API.
Now I am trying to download this report using report api which is working fine, But now I am trying to set the report type to "_GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_" so that I get requested report list for only this type of report.
I am using the code below but it's giving me this error

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object in
>   /AmazonAPI/ReportsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Client.php on
>   line 1605"

```
$config = array(
            'ServiceURL' => $serviceURL,
            'ProxyHost' => null,
            'ProxyPort' => -1,
            'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
        );
        $service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
        $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, $config, $APPLICATION_NAME, $APPLICATION_VERSION);

        //===========================GETS REPORT ID     
        $request_report_list = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportListRequest();
        $request_report_list->setMerchant($MERCHANT_ID);
        $request_report_list->setAcknowledged(false);
        $request_report_list->setMarketplace($MARKETPLACE_ID);
        $request_report_list->setReportTypeList(array("TypeList" => "_GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_"));
```

Comment: Works fine after removing "getType()" in line no. 1605 in Client.php So from foreach  ($reportTypeList->getType() as $typeIndex => $type) to "foreach  ($reportTypeList as $typeIndex => $type)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to create a class of type typelist and send as parameter

```
$TypeList = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_TypeList();
$TypeList->setType('_GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_');
$request_report_list->setReportTypeList($TypeList);
```

Comment: Works fine after removing "getType()" in line no. 1605 in Client.php So from foreach ($reportTypeList->getType() as $typeIndex => $type) to "foreach ($reportTypeList as $typeIndex => $type)"

Comment: Of course, but you're changing the official library, is not a problem in the library, the problem is that the parameter was not correct, but if it works do not worry more.

Comment: Ooh Thanks @mameyugo I hope amazon start working on better documentation on their APIs.